# Overwrite textbox Speech to Text with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

With web speech API, I'm converting speech to text using html and javascript. How can I over write the text box each time I speak? For the current moment each time I speak the new next delete the previous. How can I keep all the texts in the text box without deleting the previous after speaking?

```js
    var btnSpeechEnfSig = document.getElementById('btnSpeechEnfSig');

    btnSpeechEnfSig.onclick = function() {
    var output = document.getElementById("enf_signopsis");
    // get action element reference
    var action = document.getElementById("actionSpeechEnfSig");
    runSpeechRecognition(output,action);
    }


    function runSpeechRecognition(output,action) {

    var SpeechRecognition = SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition;
    var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();

    // This runs when the speech recognition service starts
    recognition.onstart = function() {
    action.innerHTML = "<small>escuchando, habla...</small>";
    };

    recognition.onspeechend = function() {
    action.innerHTML = "<small>grabación terminó...</small>";
    recognition.stop();
    
    }

    // This runs when the speech recognition service returns result
    recognition.onresult = function(event) {
    var transcript = event.results[0][0].transcript;
    
    output.value += transcript;
  }
    };
```

```html
    <button type="button" id="btnSpeechEnfSig"  ><i class="fa fa-microphone""></i></button>
    <span id="actionSpeechEnfSig"></span>
    <textarea rows="6"  id="enf_signopsis" ></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `output.value += transcript;`.

Comment: wonderful, thank you so much, you have made my day. By the way, is there a way to make it work on firefox, it works only on chrome. ?

Comment: @Diasline it works only on chrome ? weird, you could try `ouput

Comment: @Diasline Weird that it works only on Chromem i do not know a way to circumvent this. But maybe your Firefox is just too old ?

Comment: I have updated to last version of firefox and it still not working. You can still check the codes in firefox browser. In chrome it's perfect

Comment: @Diasline it cannot work, because Firefox has no speech recognition API, only Google's Chrome has,

Comment: In this case what would you please propose me to do to achieve with firefox as well ?

Comment: @Diasline it is not possible with the builtin API because Firefox has no speech recognition.  But you could take a look at [third party speech recognition libraries](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/163/top-7-best-voice-commands-and-speech-recognition-related-javascript-libraries)